# Does Guava provide a Predicates.is(T) (a la Predicates.equalTo(T t)) for identity equality?

Tags: java, guava

I didn't find the identity-equality `Predicate` I expected to in `com.google.common.base.Predicates` so I whipped this up.  I've found it useful for assertions in unit tests about the precise behavior of collections (e.g., `Multiset<T>`)  Does this already exist?  If not, I think it should but maybe there's something I'm not considering?

```java
/** @see Predicates#is(Object) */
private static class IsPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T>, Serializable {
  private final T target;

  private IsPredicate(T target) {
    this.target = target;
  }
  public boolean apply(T t) {
    return target == t;
  }
  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return target.hashCode();
  }
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof IsPredicate) {
      IsPredicate<?> that = (IsPredicate<?>) obj;
      return target.equals(that.target);
    }
    return false;
  }
  @Override public String toString() {
    return "Is(" + target + ")";
  }
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
}

/**
 * Returns a predicate that evaluates to {@code true} if the object being
 * tested {@code ==} the given target or both are null.
 */
public static <T> Predicate<T> is(T target) {
  return (target == null)
      ? Predicates.<T>isNull()
      : new IsPredicate<T>(target);
}
```

Comment: If the whole point of the class is to provide a predicate for reference equality (same instance) then isn't your `equals()` implementation rather broken since it uses `target.equals()`?

Comment: By the way I do think it's a cool idea and probably has some limited use.  I don't see too much use for it in production.  For example, you wouldn't need to filter a collection down to a subset that contains only an object for which you have a reference already.  Also, 95% of the time in non-test code you care about actual equality, not identity equality.  But I could definitely see the use in testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't, and it's also in the [idea graveyard](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard) as something that won't be done (`Predicates.sameAs`). I imagine it's more or less for the reasons Mark Peters gives.

Comment: <Slaps Head/>. Can't believe I didn't look in the idea graveyard - thanks.

Comment: Yeah, we used to have it and then we found that everyone who used it would have been just fine using equalTo(); we had no use cases that really needed sameAs() and it's easy enough to make it when you need it.